# Why does prediction work without rescaling with load_img while using rescaling with ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am implementing a fairly common method of doing binary image classification using Keras. The code I used for reference could be found here but it looks similar to many such code examples I saw online.

https://github.com/tatsuyah/CNN-Image-Classifier/blob/master/src/train-binary.py

https://github.com/tatsuyah/CNN-Image-Classifier/blob/master/src/predict-binary.py

Important parts are here

```
# while training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255, # rescaling to range 0..1
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)


# But while doing prediction
x = load_img(file, target_size=(img_width,img_height))
x = img_to_array(x)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
array = model.predict(x)
```

As you can see from the above code there is no apparent rescaling happening while predicting. I, in fact, checked to see if x variable had the range of 0..1 but it had values in the range of 0..255

Does predict do that automatically somehow or predict can work despite training data having 0..1 range?